# Extreme landings alarm types

Tags: flight-simulator

I was playing extreme landings pro with failure enabled but i've encountered a bunch of alarm types that does not in the tutorials such as tires etc. 
What are all alarm types and workarunds in extreme landing. I couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: Since this is a question about a particular computer game, I think you might have better luck asking over at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why two down-votes here? The question explicitly states failed effort of research; it is a useful question, to those who play that game; and it is fairly clearly written as well. Unfortunately it does not appear to be on-topic to this exchange, but that does not equate to requiring down-votes, at least to my understanding of the system.

Comment: I don't think simulations are game, at least all the terms appeared in simulators are similar with real ones, arent' they. And I don't think every member here has his/her own real plane right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Tire Alarm" would be that the tires do not have enough pressure in them. You deal with that one by coming in at a lower speed. Once you land, you would have to compensate for whatever direction the airplane lurches in.
2. For the airspeed and altimeter alarms, just use your memory of about how a certain altitude and speed looks like. For airspeed, the engine sound might also help.
3. For any of the braking alarms (brake, air brake, thrust reverse) just go in a little slower and lower and prepare for a longer landing roll.
4. Flaps alarm. Just fly and land normally, not too much of a problem with that.
5. ASY and No Fuel (for certain engines) alarms would best be counteracted by just using more throttle than you normally would since a number of engines would not be working.

Note: Tire, airspeed, altimeter, braking, and flaps alarms can't be "fixed" from your controls. The ASY and No Fuel may be able to be fixed by transferring fuel over to the empty tank. However, in certain alarms, the fuel just leaves immediately, so forgo trying to transfer fuel over. You also want to keep your attention of your flying or you might smash into the ground while trying to take care of your alarms.

Comment: Well, now there is a quandary. This answer got down-voted. Assuming it's accurate, why should it be down-voted? it's a valid answer to the question as asked and therefore useful. It's not the answer's fault the question doesn't belong, and in fact, the question need not be down-voted either, it's a well done question, just not on topic here.

Comment: @CGCampbell Probably because it's rambling and not factually accurate (flaps, fly and land normally? - well, yes, apart from the increased approach speed and much longer rollout)

Comment: @Simon I am just answering by how the game operates. I do know that this flight simulator does have some problems with realistically imitating flight.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann That's fine, but your answer seems to be guesswork rather than fact.  For example, [see this question and answers](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/can-a-super-land-without-flaps-spoilers).  No flaps is a big deal.

Comment: @Simon I have played with that flight sim and that is what I noticed from it.

Comment: Ah, I see, You mean that's how the game behaves, not a real aircraft?

Comment: @Simon Yes, I am saying that. There are a few other non-realistic quirks too besides this one.